# How to increase DISK'S performance effectivly, using M.2 NMVE RAID?

Tags: ssd, raid

I have this motherboard http://www.huananzhi.com/html/1/184/185/index.html HUANANZHI X99 F8D and I want the outstanding speed of disks operations. People told me about "M.2 NVME -> PCIe 3.0 x4 KS-is" adapter which let me use up to two M.2 NMVE SSD on that motherboard. What if I will create a RAID of M2 nmve disks? How it might up speed of disk's operations? 50%? 75%? 100%? I want to spend money efficiently.

2. What if I will try to join in RAID the M.2 nmve + M.2  NGFF ? What if two M.2  NGFF ?
3. What is better for performance - to use original M.2 slots or an adapter "M.2 NMVE -> PCIe 3.0 "?

Great thanks!

PS: I am the part of Software Developing team, we create a system for some bureaucracy for construction industry and use technologies like Kotlin, Spring, Docker, Docker ... a lot of docker, JVM, SQL server and machine learning , I need fast computer for that.

Comment: If you had a motherboard that supported pci 4 then you could double your speed with a pcie 4.0 NVMe SSD.   Don't get the ones that look like NVMe, but are really SATA as they max out at approx 550mb/s versus 6000mb/s for the right NVMe pcie 4 storage device.

Answer (score 1):

Use Raid 1 with 2x NVMe drives. This will almost double your read speed and provide redundancy so that your system will keep working even if one drive fails.

If you have a giant budget, you can get [this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09BJ163KY), fill it with 4x identical NVMe drives, and use Raid 10. You'll get improved read and write speeds and redundancy.

If you don't need redundancy, you can use Raid 0 with 2x drives to increase read and write speeds without losing any of the drives capacity to redundancy, but if either drive fails, you will lose all the data.

NVMe drives will be faster than mSATA drives even though they may both fit in a M.2 NGFF slot.

Comment: Thank you! I need to know more about RAID 0 , 1 , 10 to choose the strategy and could you tell me about multi-OS boot process from RAID ?

Comment: sorry I need more detailed answer for users aren't familiar with creating and using RAID on their home PCs

Comment: Sorry. This is just a question and answer site. I suggest you look up a tutorial and come back if you have any questions. This is also the hardware site (not software). There are a lot of easy to find guides and plenty of friendly people here that will try to help.  :)

Comment: In both Linux and Widows, it's really easy to do with the built in partition manager. Example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID